# Choosing the right AWS Services and software tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm developing a prototype IoT application which does the following

1. Receive/Store data from sensors.
2. Web application with a web-based IDE for users to deploy simple JavaScript/Python scripts which gets executed in Docker Containers.
3. Data from the sensors gets streamed to these containers.
4. User programs can use this data to do analytics, monitoring etc.
5. The logs of these programs are outputted to the user on the webapp

[image]

**Current Architecture and Services**

1. Using one AWS EC2 instance. I chose EC2 because I was trying to figure out the architecture.
2. Stack is Node.js, RabbitMQ, Express, MySQl, MongoDB and Docker
3. I'm not interested in using AWS IoT services like AWS IoT and Greengrass
4. I've ruled out Heroku since I'm using other AWS services.

**Questions and Concerns**

**My goal is prototype development for a Beta release to a set of 50 users** 
(hopefully someone else will help/work on a production release)

1. *As far as possible, I don't want to spend a lot of time migrating between services since developing the product is key.* Should I stick with EC2 or move to Beanstalk?
2. If I stick with EC2, what is the best way to handle small-medium traffic? Use one large EC2 machine or many small micro instances?
3. **What is a good way to manage containers? Is it worth it use swarm and do container management? What if I have to use multiple instances?**
4. I also have small scripts which have status of information of sensors which are needed by web app and other services. If I move to multiple instances, how can I make these scripts available to multiple machines?
5. The above question also holds good for servers, message buses, databases etc.

My goal is certainly not production release. I want to complete the product, show I have users who are interested and of course, show that the product works!

Any help in this regard will be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you thought of using ECS? since you are using docker containers That will take most of your trouble with number 3

Comment: *I've ruled out Heroku since I'm using other AWS services.*  Heroku is hosted inside AWS, so it's still right there in close proximity to everything else, if you actually wanted to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage docker containers with least hassle in AWS, you can use Amazon ECS service to deploy your containers or else go with Beanstalk. Also you don't need to use Swarm in AWS, ECS will work for you.

Its always better to scale out rather scale up, using small to medium size EC2 instances. However the challenge you will face here is managing and scaling underlying EC2's as well as your docker containers. This leads you to use Large EC2 instances to keep EC2 scaling aside and focus on docker scaling(Which will add additional costs for you)

Another alternative you can use for the Web Application part is to use, AWS Lambda and API Gateway stack with [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/), which needs least operational overhead and comes with DevOps tools.

Comment: I'm not sure if AWS Lambda/Beanstalk is the way to go especially when the product isn't ready yet. I'm seeing if I can scale-up for #4 and #5 and use Kubernetes for #3. I can also use ECS but it's less attractive because it'll result in vendor lock-in. I might use a medium or large instance and then to run Kubernetes/ECS have 1-2 smaller instances. I feel your answer is incomplete and a little abstract. Can you expand to cover the points I have or offer more thoughts maybe?

Comment: I will update with details later today. By the way is Vendor locking in AWS Cloud a concern for your architecture? in comparison with management overhead and cost.

Comment: Yes. At-least in the product prototyping stage. Once everything is figured out, the production release/team can think about cost etc. I just want to get the product working with a small set of beta users asap without a lock-in. At this point I'm thinking of using kubernetes for scaling containers and one large instance for other services.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep your web app on Heroku and run your IoT server in AWS EC2 or AWS Lambda. Heroku is on AWS itself, so this split setup will not affect performance. You may heal that inconvenience of "sitting on two chairs" by writing a [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) script which provisions both EC2 instance and Heroku app and ties them together.

Alternatively, you can use [Dockhero](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/dockhero) add-on to run your IoT server in a Docker container alongside your Heroku app.

ps: I'm a Dockhero maintainer